# C# How to change background color of root layout in Windows Phone 8 WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, colors, background, windows-runtime

I'm trying to change the background color of the main content area in my Windows Phone 8 (WinRT) app. I've tried specifying the color (grey) by adding borders to grids and the main listview. The problem is that I can see the background color change from black to grey when I navigate between pages.

This has lead me to trying to unsuccessfully style ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush.

From here I've moved on try trying to set the RootFrame color in App.xaml.cs. But I've only been able to find examples of this being done for Silverlight apps. I have part of what I think is the right c# code in app.xaml.cs but I'm stuck trying to formulate it correctly to actually specify a hex value for the color.

```
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            rootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush();
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me in my App.xaml.cs:

```
if (rootFrame == null)
{
// Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
rootFrame = new Frame();

SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush();
color.Color = (Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0xFF, 44, 50, 50));
rootFrame.Background = color;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use this :-

   ```
   rootFrame.Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));
   ```
2. Or If you've hex string then you can use this method :-

   ```
   public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
   {
       return new SolidColorBrush(
           Color.FromArgb(
               255,
               Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
               Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
               Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16)
           )
       );
   }
   ```
3. Or create a Converter from Hexadecimal Value to SolidColorBrush as a
   common code that you can use in other places too..

   ```
   namespace YourNamespaceHere
   {
       using System;
       using Windows.UI;
       using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
       using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;

       public class HexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// Converts a hexadecimal string value into a Brush.
           /// </summary>
           public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
           {   
               byte alpha;
               byte pos = 0;

               string hex = value.ToString().Replace("#", "");

               if (hex.Length == 8)
               {
                   alpha = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);
                   pos = 2;
               }
               else 
               {
                   alpha = System.Convert.ToByte("ff", 16);
               }

               byte red = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

               pos += 2;
               byte green = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

               pos += 2;
               byte blue = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

               return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue));
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// And back again.
           /// </summary>
           public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
           {
               SolidColorBrush val = value as SolidColorBrush;
               return "#" + val.Color.A.ToString() + val.Color.R.ToString()  + val.Color.G.ToString() +  val.Color.B.ToString();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: 'rootFrame.Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));' gives me the following: The name 'Color' does not exist in the current context. That appears to be the solution for Silverlight apps?

Comment: Got further with this: `rootFrame.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0xFF, 44, 50, 50));` Only issue that I have now is that all of the regular Grid elements overwrite this background color - so it is immediately overlayed with black grids (the default for the dark theme).